# Which "Individual Component" from the Visual Studio installer is suitable for Rust development?

Tags: visual-studio, rust

I have a fully updated install of Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (currently 15.9.2) on my machine, and I want to do some Rust coding. The Rust installer tells me to install "Visual C++" build tooling, but I can't seem to figure out which one is needed.

That is, I tried installing "VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16", but when I do `cargo run` on my hello world application, it halts with a message:

> error: linker `link.exe` not found

I don't want to go rampant and install *all* the C++ components in the installer, just the one I need. I'd prefer to install it as part of the Visual Studio installer, if possible.

**Which "Individual Component" in the Visual Studio installer do I need for Rust?**

Here's what's currently checked:

[image: C++ components]

[image: C++ activities]

As a workaround, I was advised to run `rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` which at least allows me to run the hello world example. (Or perhaps this is in fact a proper *solution* even?)

Comment: Have you verified, that your link.exe is in your `PATH`? https://users.rust-lang.org/t/problems-with-installing-rust-on-windows/9349

Comment: No, I had not, but have just checked and "The term 'link.exe' is not recognized..." if I try to invoke it.

Answer (score 4):

Installing any "VC++ toolset" should be enough to get `cargo run` to link properly. It [looks like the minimum dependencies are](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs/issues/1462):

> Required dependencies are `VC++ 2017 version 15.7 v14.14 latest v141 tools` and `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0)`

Answer (score 2):

Note that VC does **not** add its tools to the path (so that you can have multiple versions of the MS toolchain installed in parallel). Instead it adds entries to your Start menu like: "VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 command prompt" (not sure of the name), that allow you to start a command prompt with the proper path. This should also be possible from a VS toolbar button or menu entry.

You can't start `cargo` from a generic command prompt, you need to open the prompt with one of the above solutions.

Alternatively, you need to run `c:\path\to\your\VS\installation\VCVARS.BAT` inside your prompt to set the correct path before running `cargo`.